# overlay for lowerpart of a breakable tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I would like to define an special design for the lower part of a breakable tcolorbox. And for `lowerpart` I mean all contents defined after `\tcblower`.
I would like to define some overlay or borders or whatever for the lower part independently of how many pages it covers or when it starts in a broken box.

Let's suppose something like

[image]

A crossing line covers the lowerpart of the box. When the tcolorbox is not breakable there is no problem, because `segmentation` node can be used as top reference for `lowerpart`.

When this design is applied to a broken box I would like that this crossing line appears in all fragments which contain parts of the lowerpart. If some fragment contains part of upper part and part of lower, the line will cover only the lower part of the fragment (like in previous figure) but will cover the whole fragment if they only contain lower part.

As an example, following figure shows a "correct" left page but a incorrect "right" because the red line doesn't starts at top left corner.

[image]

Another example, on left page there is an unbroken box with a "correct" red line and the first fragment of a broken one with an "incorrect" red line. It shouldn't be here because this fragment doesn't contains any lowerpart text.

[image]

From previous examples it seems that `segmentation` is remembered from previous uses or definitions and is not deleted in fragments where it should not exist.

Previous examples have been obtained with variations of:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
    enhanced, 
    breakable, 
    overlay unbroken={%
        \path[draw=red] (segmentation.west)--(frame.south east);},
    overlay broken={%
        \path[draw=red] (segmentation.west)--(frame.south east);},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
This is the upper part
\tcblower
\lipsum[3]
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1-2]
\tcblower
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

As an alternative I tried with a `bicolor` skin but `segmentation style` options is not enough flexible and `segmentation code` doesn't respect the frame format.

Could you suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: Is the concept of the `lower` part of a tcolorbox still maintained in breaking? Does `overlay last=` help instead of `overlay broken=`...?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Let me some minutes to rephrase the question, I'll try to make it more clear.

Comment: I think I have understood your question, but I believe you have to make something like a query whether the box is broken, has a middle or last part. I could imagine, that for the last broken part of the box, `segmentation` is the wrong node name, but must be replaced by `frame`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I hope the question is more clear now. The main problem is how to know which fragments contain `lowerpart`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I think the lower part (or parts of it), if broken, will be an 'ordinary' `tcolorbox` later on, so for this box `segmentation` is the wrong node, but rather `frame`. I agree with you that it is difficult to identify which box has (portions) of the lower or upper part

Comment: It should be possible to add to \tcblower a command which sets a label connected to e.g. the number of the current box. You could then check in the overlay code if the label is on the current page.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Do you know if there exist any boolean that switches when lower part is present?

Comment: @Ignasi: No, not yet. At least the manuals gives no clue (or I have not found it yet), perhaps one has to scan the code?

Comment: @Ignasi: How about something like `before upper={\global\lowerparttrue}` and a `\newif\iflowerpart`?  (I think `\global` is necessary here, as well as `before=\global\lowerpartfalse`) and applying the `overlay first pre` hooks?

Comment: I think there's no easy way to figure out if there's a lower box and where the break occurs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a macro called `tcbsegmentstate` which contains `0`, `1`, or `2`. This macro is set for every unbroken box and every broken partial box with the following meaning:

- `0`: The current (partial) box contains only an upper part.
- `1`: The current (partial) box contains an upper and a lower part. The `segmentation` node can be used for positioning.
- `2`: The current (partial) box contains only a lower part.

The example code can be adapted as follows:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{%
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    overlay={%
      \ifcase\tcbsegmentstate
        % 0 = Box contains only an upper part
      \or%
        % 1 = Box contains an upper and a lower part
        \path[draw=red] (segmentation.west)--(frame.south east);
      \else%
        % 2 = Box contains only a lower part
        \path[draw=red] (frame.north west)--(frame.south east);
      \fi%
    }
    #1
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
This is the only part
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
This is the upper part
\tcblower
\lipsum[3]
\end{mybox}

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1-2]
\tcblower
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. May be you could consider documenting this macro.

Comment: @Ignasi You may be right. In this case, I would rename the macro into something 'officially' like `\tcbsegmentstate` to separate it from internal stuff.

Comment: Update: `\tcbsegmentstate` is now part of the documentation and `\tcb@segment@state` no longer works.